# Posts not being ordered randomly

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to have random posts appear in this post loop:

[image: Home page post loop screenshot]

Even though I've added `'orderby' => 'rand',` it still displays the same 4 posts always. Here's my complete code for the post loop:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
'post_status'   => 'publish',
'orderby'       => 'title',
'orderby' => 'rand',
'cat' => '3',
'order'         => 'ASC',
'posts_per_page'    => 4
));
$post_count = $query->post_count;
$posts_per_column = ceil($post_count / 4);
$rows = array();
$count = 0;
while ($query->have_posts())
{ $query->the_post();
if($rows[$count] == ""){ $rows[$count] = ''; }
            $rows[$count] = $rows[$count] . '<div class="col-post"><div class="post-title"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></div></div>';
                                            $count++;
                                            if ($count == $posts_per_column ) { $count = 0; }
                                            }
                            foreach ($rows as $row) { echo $row . ''; }
        wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: I suppose it's safe to assume there are more than 4 posts to display?  Do you have a caching plugin that might be preventing actual interaction with the database?

Comment: You also have 2 different "orderby" elements, and an "order" element.  I recommend removing the others.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently running two `orderby` arguments, which cause one of them to be ignored. You do understand that ordering by `'orderby' => 'title',` AND `'orderby' => 'rand',` are not compatible.

The following should work:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'orderby' => 'RAND',
  'cat' => '3',
  'posts_per_page' => 4
) );
```

### orderby (string | array)

> **Sort retrieved posts by parameter. Defaults to ‘date (post_date)’. One or more options can be passed.**
> ...
> ‘rand‘ – Random order.
> ‘title‘ – Order by title.

Furthermore, the `'order' => 'ASC',` **is not required** (It's just getting ignored, you're pasing and argument for nothing wich slows the query) as you're using `'orderby' => 'RAND',`, by default the value is set to `'orderby' => 'DESC',`

### order (string | array)

> **Designates the ascending or descending order of the ‘orderby‘ parameter. Defaults to ‘DESC’. An array can be used for multiple order/orderby sets.**
> ‘ASC‘ – ascending order from lowest to highest values (1, 2, 3; a, b, c).
> ‘DESC‘ – descending order from highest to lowest values (3, 2, 1; c, b, a).

*Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters*

Comment: Thank you for helping! For some reason, it still didn't pull up the random order. I don't have a cache plugin (but the server on wpEngine hosting does, I believe). I ended up doing removing the 'orderby => 'title',' as was suggested and then added ''offset' => 1,' and that worked (it's not random, but at least it changes our the recently published posts... before it just kept the same post in place).  Thanks again!